# Communicating between docker containers

Tags: docker

I'm still a newbie and trying to learning the docker concept. I want to read the JSON file present in one Ubuntu container from the another Ubuntu container. How to do this in docker? Note that, I have to send the JSON from the first container through HTTP. Any idea on how to implement this? Any explanation or sample code on this would be really great.

Answer (score 1):

If your first docker container declare a [`VOLUME`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#volume), the other can be [run with `--volumes-from=<first_container>`](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container).

That would mount the declared path of the first container into the second one, effectively sharing a file or folder from the first container in the second.

Note that a container which is just created (not `docker run`, but `docker create`) is effectively a data volume container, there only to be mounted (`--volumes-from`) by other containers.

---

With http, that means the second container must know about the first (and its [`EXPOSE`'d](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#expose) ports)

You will run the second container with `--link=alias:firstContainer`: that will allow you to contact alias:port, which is actually the url+port of the first container.
See "[Communication across links](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/#communication-across-links)"

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, actually I forget that there is a way directly through sharing volumes. But I want to do this through HTTP. Sorry for the confusion..

Comment: @Udhayakumar I have edited the answer to include http access.